# Find the integral solution with minimum sum given the product is constant.

Tags: number-theory, optimization

> Let $x,y,z,n$ be positive integers such that $n$ has at least three prime divisors.
> Find the minimum of $x+y+z$ such that $xyz=n$.

First, note that $x,y,z$ must be positive integers.

Consider $n=945$. Then its prime factorization is $3\cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$.
The following is my approach:
Choose two smallest integers in the prime factorization, which are $3,3$ and multiply them, we get $$9\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$$
Next choose two smallest integers among the numbers above, which are $3,5$ and multiply them, we get
$$9\cdot 15\cdot 7$$
So the minimum of $x+y+z$ should be $9+15+7=31$.

My question is: Is there a general solution for the minimum of $x+y+z$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: I just found a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3068687/329252) and the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3068982/329252) suggests a different and more general algorithm, which remains imperfect though.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Given prime factorization $n=\prod_p p^{n_p}$, there are $\prod_p (n_p+1)$ possible factors.  For each factor $j=\prod_p p^{j_p}$, where $j_p \le n_p$, let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_j$ be the number of times the factor is used.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_j j x_j$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_j x_j &= 3 \tag1 \\
\sum_j j_p x_j &= n_p &&\text{for all $p$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ selects three factors.  Constraint $(2)$ uses each prime factor the correct number of times.

For example, $n=2160=2^4 3^3 5^1$ has $n_2=4$, $n_3=3$, and $n_5=1$, and there are $(4+1)(3+1)(1+1)=40$ factors.  An optimal solution is $x_{12}=2$, $x_{15}=1$, with objective value $2 \cdot 12 + 1 \cdot 15 = 39$.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an oversized comment rather than an answer, but here goes: I don't think that a precise specification can be obtained. If we call this minimum sum $S(n)$ (when it exists), then I don't see how to obtain better bounds than this trivial one:
$$3\sqrt[3]{n} \leqslant S(n) \leqslant \frac{n}{4}+4$$

A few examples in the small span between $2160$ and $2176$:
$$ \begin{array}{ll}
2160 = 2^4\cdot 3^3\cdot 5 &\to S(2160)=(2\cdot 2\cdot 3)+(2\cdot 2\cdot 3)+(3\cdot 5) &= 39 \\
2164 = 2^2\cdot 541 &\to S(2164)=(2)+(2)+(541) &= 545 \\
2168 = 2^3\cdot 271 &\to S(2168)=(2)+(2\cdot 2)+(271) &= 277 \\
2172 = 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 181 &\to S(2172)=(3)+(2\cdot 2)+(181) &= 188 \\
2176 = 2^7\cdot 17 &\to S(2176)=(2\cdot 2\cdot 2)+(2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2)+(17) &= 41 \\
\end{array} $$
We see that $S(n)$ varies from very close to the lower bound, quickly up to the upper bound, and rapidly back down close to the lower bound. Given how clueless we are about finding the factors of an arbitrary $n$, it seems unlikely that we could narrow it down any better.

Note: $2160$ is interesting, because it demonstrates that your algorithm is not bullet-proof. Following your procedure, we would have:
$$\begin{array}{l}
2160 &= (2\cdot 2)\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 5 \\
&= (2\cdot 2)\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5 \\
&= (3\cdot 3)\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 4\cdot 5 \\
&= (3\cdot 4)\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 9 \\
&= (4\cdot 5)\cdot 9\cdot 12 \\
&= 9\cdot 12\cdot 20 \\
\end{array}$$
which is technically correct, but gives us a sum of $41$, when $39$ is achievable.

---

[**Edit**] An illustration of my so far failed attempts at improving the algorithm: I thought that the algorithm could perhaps be amended with a rule stating that groups of $3$ identical factors should first be "isolated" from the computation, provided it leaves $3$ or more factors to process, and "distributed" at the end of the process. So, for instance:
$$\begin{array}{l}
2160 &= [2\cdot 2\cdot 2]\cdot [(2\cdot 3)\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 5] \\
&= [2\cdot 2\cdot 2]\cdot [(3\cdot 3)\cdot 5\cdot 6] \\
&= [2\cdot 2\cdot 2]\cdot [5\cdot 6\cdot 9] \\
&= (2\cdot 5)\cdot (2\cdot 6)\cdot (2\cdot 9) \\
&= 10\cdot 12\cdot 18
\end{array}$$
A bit better, but still not good enough.

*[Thanks to RobPratt for pointing out that $40$ still wasn't optimal]*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know how you come up with the value of $S(n)$? using software?

Comment: I calculated the examples above manually, in fact, using your recipe. I was about to post when I realized that I could do better than $41$ for $2160$. I've been trying to find a (provably) better strategy, but it still escapes me at the moment.

Comment: For $n=2160$, you can do better: $12+12+15=39$.